# Is there a Match like syntax for LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, pattern-matching, strategy-pattern

Here is a case I'm trying to solve elegantly. Let's say I have an enumerable (and it might be a rather large enumerable that I'd prefer to enumerate only once). Let's say also that I have specific operations that I want to run if the object returned in the sequence matches certain conditions for the operation.

In a functional language, I can set up a sequence of matches that would execute when the match is found. I want something like this in C#. Using LINQ if possible.

The closest I've come is using the strategy pattern with a simple rules engine that calls each registered strategy in sequence until a match is found. Is there a simpler approach?

Something I would like to do is.

```
myEnum.Match((item)=>item.MatchesCondition, (item)=>ExecuteFunction(item))
  .Match((item)=>item.MatchesSomeOtherCondition, (item)=>ExecuteSomeOtherFunction(item));
```

Comment: can you show some kind of example code? I'm a little confused on what exactly you're asking for.

Comment: I was doing so just as you typed your comment.

Comment: Are you trying to match a particular item in the enumerator or are wanting to only call the function when you find a match on a set?  I mean you could easily create an extension method for the above logic or just use `foreach` with `if/else` or a `switch`

Comment: Why not just use a `Where()` and then a `foreach` on the results?

Comment: Should `ExecuteSomeOtherFunction` be called for a given object if `ExecuteFunction` has already been called for that same object?

Comment: I don't want fall through execution. Basically if the first Match is made all subsequent matches should be ignored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create an [extension method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) `Match`:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> Match<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, bool> condition, Action<T> action)
    {
        foreach (T item in items)
        {
            if (condition(item))
            {
                action(item)
            }
            else
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will loop through every item in `items` and:

- If they match the condition, execute `action`
- Otherwise, return the item through the [iterator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/65zzykke(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I like it! This is perfect and it also prevents subsequently chained matches from firing.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use existing LINQ functionality, something like this:

```
SomeList.Where(item => item.Equals(item));
```

In case you do not want to filter for an exact match but for a "contains" you can use this expression:

```
SomeList.Where(item => item.Contains(item));
```

Comment: This would just filter the set... a closer reponse would be a switch in a select statement.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Dictionary that holds conditions and associated actions, allowing you to continue to loop through a series of conditions until a match is found and then invoke the associated action.

```
void Main()
{
    var collection = new List<string> { "One", "Two" };

    var dict = new Dictionary<Func<string, bool>, Action<string>>
    {
        { ConditionOne, ActionOne },
        { ConditionTwo, ActionTwo },
    };

    Match(collection, dict);
}

public void Match<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, 
    Dictionary<Func<T, bool>, Action<T>> matchMap)
{
    var wasMatched = false;
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        if (wasMatched) break;

        foreach (var pair in matchMap)
        {
            if (wasMatched) break;

            if (pair.Key(item))
            {
                pair.Value(item);
                wasMatched = true;
            }   
        }
    }
}

public bool ConditionOne<T>(T item)
{
    return false;
}

public void ActionOne<T>(T item)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

public bool ConditionTwo<T>(T item)
{
    return true;
}

public void ActionTwo<T>(T item)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```